# Searching a word in a document in C# is errors

Tags: c#

I wrote the code for: searching a word in a document that works without problems in the Console Application, but does not work in ASP.NET Application when I click the button:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

 Application objWordApp = new Application();
                objWordApp.Visible = false;
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                Document objDoc;
                objDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open(fileURL, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                ref missing, ref missing);

                object findText = "Tags";

                objDoc.Content.Find.ClearFormatting();
                try
                {
                    if (objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(ref findText,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Text found: Name document - " + "'" + docTitle + "'");
                    }
                    objDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                    objWordApp.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    objDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                    objWordApp.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                test11.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
```

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory
>   for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed
>   due to the following error: 80070005 Access denied. (Exception to
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I looked at a lot of information on the forums, did everything as written in the article, nothing helps, the error was not eliminated.

1.[DCOM Error : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.](https://indiandeve.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/dcom-error-retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-000209ff-0000-0000-c000-000000000046-failed-due-to-the-following-error-80070005/)

2.[Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890906/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-000209ff-0000-0000-c0)

Comment: It runs on the IIS right?. It is asp.net aspx application or MVC. Were you kept in your file location?

Comment: @Saravanakumar Natarajan "asp.net aspx application" - file location is URL http://sp-test/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/Base.docx, but the Console Application is working.

Comment: What is the version of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word dll used

Comment: version 15.0.0.0

Comment: I'm trying with this code asp.net application.  I'm not getting this error.

Comment: Problem with in my Windows server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188053/discussion-between-saravanakumar-natarajan-and-fox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this One

**Step1:**

Ref this link : [Interop.Word Documents.Open is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837437/interop-word-documents-open-is-null)

If you are still looking for the answer I have found it just a moment ago for my project.

Open DCOM Config Settings:

1. Start -> dcomcnfg.exe
2. Computer
3. Local Computer
4. Config DCOM
5. Search for Microsoft Word 97-2003 Documents -> Properties
   Tab Identity, change from Launching User to Interactive User

**Step2:**

Go to your **Project** do the below change..

[image]

**Step3:**

Go to the **IIS Server**, Add the **Application Pool** like a below **Configuration** and **Map** into to your site or application.

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution, nothing has changed, I reinstall MS Office (((